# Is there a way to make this slideshow move automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use i slider ( that i make myself ) and it's working .. but by clicking on the number of each tab

and i wanna make it go through each image automatically each 5 seconds or whatever ..

this is the html and javascript codes :

html :

```
<div class="slide2">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="slide-6" class="tab-slide" style="display: block">
        <div class="desc">
            <div>Slide 6 - tab1</div>
        </div>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-7" class="tab-slide">
        <div class="desc" style="width:320px;padding-top:236px;height:120px;">
            <h1>Slide 7 - tab2</h1>
        </div>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-8" class="tab-slide">
        <div class="desc" style="width:320px;">
            <h1>Slide 8 - tab3</h1>
        </div>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-9" class="tab-slide">
        <div class="desc" style="width:320px;">
            <h1>Slide 9 - tab4</h1>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<ul id="nav2">
    <li><a class="current" id="tab-6" href="#tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab-7" href="#tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab-8" href="#tab">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab-9" href="#tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

javascript :

```
        $(function(){

        $('#tabs #nav2 li a').click(function(){

            var currentNum = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
            $('#tabs #nav2 li a').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            $('#tabs #content .tab-slide').hide(1);
            $('#tabs #content #slide-'+currentNum+'.tab-slide').show(300);
        });

        $('#tabsSlide #nav2 li a').click(function(){

            var currentNum = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
            $('#tabsSlide #nav2 li a').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            $('#tabsSlide #content .tab-slide').slideUp(300);
            $('#tabsSlide #content #slide-'+currentNum+'.tab-slide').slideDown(300);
        });

    });
```

CSS :

```
    .slide2 {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:574px;
}
#tabs {
    width:574px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
#tabs #nav2 {
    float: right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:574px;
}
#tabs #nav2 li{
    display:inline;
}
#tabs #nav2 li a {
    display:block;
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:55px;
    line-height:55px;
    color:#0096d6;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-image: url('images/slide/a.png');
}
#tabs #nav2 li a:hover {
    background:#dddede;
}
#tabs #nav2 li a.current {
    background:#dddede;
    color:#666666;
}
#tabs #content {
    padding:0px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    min-height: 366px;
}
#tabs #content ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#c1c0c0;
}
.tab-list {
    width:115px;
    float:right;
    line-height:200%;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color:#c1c0c0;
}
.tab-list a {
    color:#c1c0c0;
}
.tab-list a:hover {
    color:#0198d8;
}
#tabs #content .tab-slide { display: none; }
#tabs #content .tab-slide p {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 11px tahoma;
    line-height: 150%;
}
.slide2 #slide-6 {
    background-image: url('images/slide/1.jpg');
    width:574px;
    height:366px;
}
.slide2 #slide-7 {
    background-image: url('images/slide/2.jpg');
    width:574px;
    height:366px;
}
.slide2 #slide-8 {
    background-image: url('images/slide/3.jpg');
    width:574px;
    height:366px;
}
.slide2 #slide-9 {
    background-image: url('images/slide/4.jpg');
    width:574px;
    height:366px;
}
```

Thanks!

---

and i don't need the mouseover pause ..

i just want to make the content move automatically that's all !

Comment: ... do you have any CSS to show? actually it's quite easy, but please post your CSS

Answer (score 0):

This should cycle for you (every 5 seconds)...without all of your code, and adding hooks into it, this seems the simplest way.  It will not pause the cycle timer when on mouseover as many sliders do, unless you add that functionality as well.

```
var to;
function cycle() {
    $('#tabsSlide #nav2 li a').click();
    to = setTimeout(cycle,5000);
}
cycle();
```

Note, to add the pause effect, you need to stop/restart the timeout call by clearing the timeout on mouseover and resuming on mouseout.  if you want to resume the timer instead of restarting it, you need to do some math to do that as well.